# Clang_complete not worrking

Tags: clang, vim, vim-plugin, clang-complete

unfortunately I can't manage to make clang_complete work and I could need your help.
I've already compiled vim 7.4 with python support. Here is the output of `vim --version | grep python`:

```
+cryptv          +linebreak       +python/dyn      +viminfo
-cscope          +lispindent      +python3/dyn     +vreplace
```

I followed this guide: https://vtluug.org/wiki/Clang_Complete

Please note that I've started from a clean installation (i.e. no other plugins and no further entries in my `.vimrc` (except for those shown in the guide above)).

According to the tutorials I've seen so far everything should be working.
However, if I try to get code completion for the following example nothing happens. If I press `<c-x><x-u>` I receive the error "completefunc not set".

```
#include <string>

int main()
{
   std::string s;
   s.
}
```

Moreover, I've installed the newest version of clang from source and it in my `$PATH`.

Is there a way to verify that clang_complete is actually installed?

What might cause this problem?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You can use `:scriptnames` in vim to see a list of enabled plugins

Comment: I suggest you use the `youcompleteme` plugin. I find it much better than clang

Comment: youcompleteme is not really working either, it always shows the following error: "The ycmd server SHUT DOWN (restart with :YcmRestartServer). Stderr (last 30 lines):" and "HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1' ...) ... connection refused"

Comment: Does it work after `:e`? Are there any buffer local variables of clang, e.g. `b:clang_something` (try tab complete it for `:echo b:clang_`)?

Comment: autocompletion for :echo b:clang_<something> works. Moreover, I just installed supertab. I'm able to auto-complete stuff that is defined in the local file but the "string s." is still not suggesting anything. Is it possible that clang doesn't find <string> ?

Comment: On the other hand, even if I add the include path to <string> into the .clang_complete file, I still receive the error "Pattern not found".

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
filetype plugin indent on
```

to your vimrc, its missing from the vimrc snippet in the link. This tells vim to do filetype detection and fire autocommands related to those file types. Without it you won't run the following autocommands.

```
au FileType c,cpp,objc,objcpp call <SID>ClangCompleteInit()
au FileType c.*,cpp.*,objc.*,objcpp.* call <SID>ClangCompleteInit()
```

Which probably initalize ClangComplete.

Comment: that's not working either. This is the error message that I get: E117: Unknown function: <SNR>2_ClangCompleteInit. Moreover, :scriptnames shows that the clang_complete.vim addon is loaded.